# Confusing about how the lemma can be stated

Tags: logic, proof-writing, set-theory, transfinite-induction

Let's consider the following:

**Lemma**  Let $g\in F(\beta)$  and $f\in \Bbb R^\Bbb R$ such that $f\restriction M= g\restriction M$ for some $M\subset \mathbb R$. Then $f\in F(\beta).$

Of course, no one will be able to follow the question without saying what $F(\beta)$ is. In my case, $F(\beta)$ needs to be constructed by transfinite induction or another way.  I know the most natural way is that construct $F(\beta)$ and then state the lemma. But for some, this was hard for me. This is why I am looking for another way to do this. Here I have some questions:

> Q1   Is true if I state the lemma, then give the construction of $F(\beta)$, and provide the proof of the lemma? If so, If this kind of idea sometimes use in book or journal paper?

> Q2 If not, do you recommend an idea to play around this without introducing $F(\beta)$ first?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $F$?  What is $\beta$?

Comment: @lulu, you may misunderstand the question. I was asking can I state the lemma and then say what is $F(\beta)$. I am not asking how I can prove the theorem.

Comment: Generally speaking, it is **not** a good idea to use notation before you explain what it means. If you can explain what $F(\beta)$ is without giving an explicit construction, then it's okay to do so and then  mention it in a lemma before you provide an explicit construction. But if the "construction" is essentially the only way you have to explain what $F(\beta)$ is, then you should not delay that explanation to after you mention it; construct it first. You may introduce the construction by saying how it will be used or why it is important, or the intuition behind the construction.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I would recommend that you write your comments as an answer.

Comment: I can imagine some circumstances in which details are delayed, but they should be details, not core concepts.  "If $f(x)$ is a smooth function satisfying some technical growth properties that will be detailed below, then..."  is fine, for instance.  The reader has enough information to grasp the statement and can easily grasp the notion that a few extra assumptions will need to be added.  But core concepts and basic definitions must come first.

Comment: @lulu, I see, thank you for your comment.

Comment: Please define $F(\beta)$. As you've phrased the Lemma, it looks like either  $F(\beta) = \emptyset$ or $F(\beta) = \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$. Suppose $F(\beta) \neq \emptyset$; let $f\in F(\beta)$. Any $g\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ agrees with $f$ on $M =\emptyset\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, so $g\in F(\beta)$. No? If not, why not?

Comment: @BrianO, Thank you for your comment. Please read the question very careful.  Even the comments above.

Comment: I read it quite carefully, which is how I noticed the issue I raised in my comment. Address my comment, and perhaps write the question more carefully.

Comment: @BrianO,  I might be wrong but I think my question is clear. Just see the two comments above.  Thank you for your time.